# Selecting specific anchor tags using python

Tags: python, html

Here are some links, I copied from a website which I am scraping. Problem is that in there sitemap some main categories appear more than one time like: "Fashion", "Audio Visual" and "Computer Servers". But I need these links only once. How can i achieve that, i used var "counter" to check the second occurrence but that didn't help either.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/networking-storage">Networking Storage</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/mobiles-tablets">Mobiles Tablets</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/fashion">Fashion</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/fashion">Fashion</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/printers-scanners">Printers Scanners</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/audio-visual">Audio Visual</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/audio-visual">Audio Visual</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/cameras">Cameras</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/computers-servers">Computers Servers</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/computers-servers">Computers Servers</a>
```

Here is my python code to fetch these links:

```
mainPage = requests.get("http://www.example.com/catalog/seo_sitemap/category/?p=1")
mainTree = html.fromstring(mainPage.text)

for mainCat in mainTree.cssselect('a'):
    print (mainCat.get('href'))
```

It prints-

```
http://www.example.com/mobiles-tablets
http://www.example.com/fashion
http://www.example.com/fashion
http://www.example.com/printers-scanners
http://www.example.com/audio-visual
http://www.example.com/audio-visual
http://www.example.com/cameras
http://www.example.com/computers-servers
http://www.example.com/computers-servers
```

While i need it like this:

```
http://www.example.com/mobiles-tablets
http://www.example.com/fashion
http://www.example.com/printers-scanners
http://www.example.com/audio-visual
http://www.example.com/cameras
http://www.example.com/computers-servers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is working for me-

```
import requests
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
from lxml import html


s='''<a href="http://www.example.com/mobiles-tablets">Mobiles Tablets</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/fashion">Fashion</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/fashion">Fashion</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/printers-scanners">Printers Scanners</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/audio-visual">Audio Visual</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/audio-visual">Audio Visual</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/cameras">Cameras</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/computers-servers">Computers Servers</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/computers-servers">Computers Servers</a>'''


#mainPage = requests.get("http://www.example.com/catalog/seo_sitemap/category/?p=1")
mainTree = html.fromstring(s)

mainTree = html.fromstring(s)
lnks = set([i.get('href') for i in mainTree.cssselect('a')])
for i in lnks:
    print i
```

It prints-

```
http://www.example.com/mobiles-tablets
http://www.example.com/printers-scanners
http://www.example.com/fashion
http://www.example.com/audio-visual
http://www.example.com/computers-servers
http://www.example.com/cameras
```

Comment: yes i know but it prints some links two times as these are in webpage like that, I need them only once.

Comment: Are links as duplicate in the site page source!

Comment: Yes links are like that in page source. But I need to achieve this programmatically somehow.